display an image in FXML
I want to display a certain image in javaFX so I am creating it in the FXML file to manipulate it later on in controller.java file but I keep getting errors after errors. this is the lastest one
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Attributes are not supported for writable property elements.
/C:/Users/ASUS/eclipse-workspace/sample/bin/sample/sample.fxml:263
at sample.Main.start(Main.java:12)
Exception running application sample.Main

this is the simple code i wrote:
<ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="83.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" >
                <image url="file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/projet/logo.png" backgroundLoading="true"/>
</ImageView>


Example FXML which displays an Image:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>

<ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <image>
      <Image url="@../../Pictures/Planet.png" />
   </image>
</ImageView>

This example was created using SceneBuilder, which I recommend rather than writing FXML from scratch by hand.
If you need to understand resource loading from FXML, how to structure your resource directories, and the @ syntax shown in this answer to load the image from a relative location, see:

Eden coding, Where to put resource files in JavaFX: Loading a resource in FXML.

FAQ

"Image is not a valid type" and when I change it to "image" I get this error instead "Parent element does not support property elements"

Sorry, StackOverflow mangled the post, leaving out the imports because I didn't indent the code correctly when I first created the answer. I edited the answer to correctly indent the code so that the imports are visible.
You need to import the right things, perhaps you are not importing a javafx.scene.image.Image or are incorrectly importing a java.awt.Image.

"Image is not a valid type" and when I change it to "image" I get this error instead "Parent element does not support property elements"
